# What path to be used for local files which are in public folder in Next js api function

Tags: node.js, next.js, vercel, jimp

I am using Jimp NPM module for image processing in NextJs api function which is to use a local font situated in public folder, This is working fine in development server but it is giving me errors when deployed to vercel, error says no such file or directory, I even tried using Jimp.FONT_SANS_64_BLACK but still it is giving me the same error.

Comment: Could you please provide a [mre]?

Comment: Related to [this](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/33736)